# How to check from where font url is calling from your website

Tags: html, css, fonts, lightbox

In google lightbox there is a font url
[image]

https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/googlesans/v44/4UasrENHsxJlGDuGo1OIlJfC6l_24rlCK1Yo_Iqcsih3SAyH6cAwhX9RPjIUvbQoi-E.woff2

I check in my code and from nowhere this font is calling. How can I check online that from where this font url is calling?

Answer (score 0):

The font, [Google Sans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_Sans), is an exclusive font that should only exist in Google things if you did not import it intentionally. You can check if you are using any Google service which may call the mysterious URL in somewhere invisible to you.